# WiFi won't connect after 22.04 upgrade

Tags: networking, upgrade, network-manager, 22.04

Yesterday I upgraded my Ubuntu 20.04 Pixelbook (full Ubuntu, no Chrome nonsense) to 22.04. After trouble even logging in to 22.04 (see [22.04 upgrade from 20.04 - stuck after login; lightdm problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426157/22-04-upgrade-from-20-04-stuck-after-login-lightdm-problem)), I managed to log in via GDM.  However, once there WiFi doesn't allow me to connect to the internet.

I can see all local WiFi networks and the OS tells me that I am 'connected,' but nothing ever actually connects and I can't access any remote sites. Or even local sites: I can't even access my WiFi router at 192.168.0.1.   I tried setting DNS to various manual options (Google, Cloudflare, etc.) to no avail.

I also tried the modifications suggested here:
[WPA2 wifi refuses to connect after upgrade to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404059/wpa2-wifi-refuses-to-connect-after-upgrade-to-22-04)
but also with no success. I can't open websites in the browser; can't ssh anywhere; can't even successfully ping.

Thoughts?

EDIT: I raw the WiFi diagnostics script located at [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and have pasted the results at https://pastebin.com/TnBLRGsz
Anyone care to interpret?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @waltinator - I posted the results above. Too detailed for my ken, but perhaps you can make sense of it? Thanks!